# auth/invalid-custom-token Firebase but it's correct?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, jwt, token

I'm getting an error whenever I generate a custom token on server side the `iat` when converted to normal time says in 16 minutes so its setting the `iat` 16 minutes after i actually login? I'm wondering it this is why I get that error as if I ran it off my pc. It shows a few seconds ago on `iat` and not in 16 minutes.

**The JWT token generated on server:**
    eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2lkZW50aXR5dG9vbGtpdC5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9nb29nbGUuaWRlbnRpdHkuaWRlbnRpdHl0b29sa2l0LnYxLklkZW50aXR5VG9vbGtpdCIsImlhdCI6MTU1MTM1MjA5OCwiZXhwIjoxNTUxMzU1Njk4LCJpc3MiOiJmaXJlYmFzZS1hZG1pbnNkay1lcXE1Z0B4ZW5vZ2FtaW5nLTI1YzA4LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiZmlyZWJhc2UtYWRtaW5zZGstZXFxNWdAeGVub2dhbWluZy0yNWMwOC5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInVpZCI6Ijc2NTYxMTk4MTIyMTMwNzYzIn0.AusdFHBo4aW35qJ0u0uwsacrfuqrvQorBTYkwfnedyqQcVjfrzKw9QAWm8p1ss4y7MgeK_AKu5Yrgls8JHIyZzYPwYBjna6dKoWK0zmDTm57iaN3UsS0aR7H4i3mdQpELgC0oVmuBa_d6NPVZeZp_1UiX6lNNALJdzrHMC91ZLhDzVqoEMTVEjqH0UxlM3e3oUz7l--0LFJEm5uVon4-exlpXWOiA6vcPCFtqExQKAAdxQF_aLL-j5ldIJj3jKd_QKTonzOR_MhzkKNEMJsZFo3isxPvtTsmsVwPoigC0jZZTkP7Ysj0fVmvIw-F7-DdeHhL-srbILGAgzRFbM0Xdg

Comment: Hi, As already said by frank, you should also include the details about the problem, code examples. Can you show how you are passing this token to your API ?

Comment: Sorry to the both of you I didn't realize this post went live I thought i canceled yesterday i resolved my issue firebase and my server had two different timezone so when it was generating the custom token it was always making it 16 minutes ahead of when the user clicked sign in

Comment: @jeremiahflores help bro ! facing the same problem. i think my server timezone and my local time zones are messed up and so i m getting the error => auth/invalid-custom-token Invalid assertion format. i m sure that my code is 100% correct !